# svn property missing after svnsync

Tags: svn, svnsync, svndump

I'm trying to svnsync a repository that has a property `svn:ignore`.

```
$ svn proplist <SOURCE_URL>
Properties on '<SOURCE_URL>':
svn:ignore
```

But after svnsync and copy-revprops I'm still missing this property on destination.

```
$ svnsync sync <DEST_URL> <SOURCE_URL>
...
$ svn proplist <DEST_URL>
$ svnsync copy-revprops <DEST_URL>
...
$ svn proplist <DEST_URL>
```

Other things I've noticed is that:

1. If I do `svnrdump dump` & `svnadmin load`, the property is present.
2. If I do `svnrdump dump -r REV --incremental`, the property is not present.

I have svn version 1.10.0 (r1827917) on MacOSX and if it's relevant, my `pre-revprop-change` hook does nothing.

What am I missing here?